Selenium Web Scraping on Google Maps: Clicking on all markers/points in view
I'm fairly new to Selenium and am looking to learn how to use it to click on all the markers or points on Google Maps in my view only. I’ve tried following some examples, but they either only work with pre-existing points in their database or rely on the Google Maps API. When I inspect Google Maps, I can only find the entire canvas element, not the individual points.
Below is my code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/@37.584135,126.9981979,19.71z?entry=ttu");
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
main_canvas = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='canvas']")))
print(main_canvas)


driver.quit()


Image of the map
I have inspected the Google Maps page and found that the entire map is rendered on a  element. Unfortunately, I can't locate specific element IDs or attributes for individual markers or points. From what I understand, Google Maps uses JavaScript to render these markers dynamically, making them difficult to interact with directly through Selenium.
Is there a method to help Selenium identify and click on these markers? If you have any suggestions or alternative approaches, I’d greatly appreciate your help!

follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78803325/how-to-detect-partially-obscured-circular-markers-in-opencv
