How to Detect Partially Obscured Circular Markers in OpenCV?
I'm working on a project that involves detecting circular markers (pins) on a map using OpenCV. The markers are sometimes partially connected to streets, making them difficult to detect using standard contour filtering methods.
I've tried several approaches to improve detection, including:

Morphological Operations: I used cv2.morphologyEx, cv2.erode, and cv2.dilate with different kernel sizes. However, these methods either missed the markers or resulted in more false positives.
Template Matching: I attempted cv2.matchTemplate, but the results were even worse and not reliable for partially obscured markers.
Color Segmentation: I implemented color segmentation, but I am concerned about the variations in street map colors across different images, which could affect the consistency of the results.

import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Read the image
image = cv2.imread('Capture.jpg')

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply thresholding to create a binary image
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
eroded = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
dilated = cv2.dilate(eroded, kernel, iterations=1)
# dilated = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_HITMISS, np.ones((3,3), np.uint8))

# Find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Debug: Display all detected contours
image_with_contours = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(image_with_contours, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image_with_contours, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('All Contours')
plt.show()

# Function to check if a contour is likely a marker pin based on circularity
def is_marker_pin(contour):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    if perimeter == 0:  # To avoid division by zero
        return False
    circularity = 4 * np.pi * (area / (perimeter * perimeter))
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    aspect_ratio = float(w) / h
    return 50 < area < 2500 and 0.5 < aspect_ratio < 2.5 and 0.6 < circularity < 1.5

# Filter contours based on shape characteristics
marker_contours = [cnt for cnt in contours if is_marker_pin(cnt)]

# Calculate and print the centroid of each marker contour
centroids = []
for cnt in marker_contours:
    M = cv2.moments(cnt)
    if M['m00'] != 0:
        cx = int(M['m10'] / M['m00'])
        cy = int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])
        centroids.append((cx, cy))
    else:
        centroids.append((0, 0))

# Debug: Display only marker contours and their centroids
image_with_marker_contours = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(image_with_marker_contours, marker_contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
for (cx, cy) in centroids:
    cv2.circle(image_with_marker_contours, (cx, cy), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image_with_marker_contours, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('Marker Contours with Centroids')
plt.show()

# Create a mask for the marker pins
mask = np.zeros_like(gray)
cv2.drawContours(mask, marker_contours, -1, (255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)

# Apply the mask to the original image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

# Display the result
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Mask')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('Markers Isolated')
plt.show()

# Print the number of detected markers and their centroids
print(f"Number of detected markers: {len(marker_contours)}")
print("Centroids of the detected markers:")
for i, (cx, cy) in enumerate(centroids):
    print(f"Marker {i + 1}: ({cx}, {cy})")




My current issue is that:

Markers that are partially connected to streets are not being detected reliably.

How can I modify my approach or contour filtering criteria to reliably detect these partially obscured markers? Are there any additional techniques or parameters I should consider to improve the detection accuracy?
Any suggestions or improvements would be greatly appreciated!

your picture of the map and markers used to be a piece of a web page. at that point, the markers were "objects" of which you could easily just get the location. why don't you work with the information at that level?

context/previous question: selenium web scraping. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78796268/selenium-web-scraping-on-google-maps-clicking-on-all-markers-points-in-view

@ChristophRackwitz i do try find the element at first however i unable to locate it so i trying to use computer vision
